# Target downvotes: informations on my profile

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes

In this question I would to know what are **all**, kindly, the links to get the informations on my profile.

For example these are related on TeX.SE.Meta

https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.tex/query/781493/25-most-downvoted-users
https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.tex/query/691667/top-downvoters

My best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below the query is a box where you can search for a different site to apply the same query to. It's a bit unintuitive. Or you can just replace the site name in the url.

[image]

Here are the links for GDSE:

https://data.stackexchange.com/graphicdesign/query/781493/25-most-downvoted-users
https://data.stackexchange.com/graphicdesign/query/691667/top-downvoters

Comment: Huh. I'm in the top 10 of downvoters. Comes with the territorry of being the single most prolific voter on this site, I guess.

Comment: Excellent answer. I would definitely vote for green ticked as well. I thank you very much. My warmest regards. Sebastiano

Comment: @Vincent To vote negatively is legal if all the conditions are correct. But voting negatively if there is a persecutory intent it is not the most appropriate way to be in a community. See all my profiles and you'll see how many negative votes I assign. I am happy when I vote positively. Regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano Oh, I know, I have given and received my share of downvotes :)

Comment: @Vincent Ahahahahah....but you'll see that you'll get more positive ones than the negative votes you've given.