# The 'Voters' page of the Users section om Meta is buggy

Tags: bug, voting, users

I was checking out the [voting totals](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) on the [Users](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users) part of the Meta site, inspired by [this question](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/target-downvotes-informations-on-my-profile). Turns out that the 'all' tab is the only tab that still displays anything. I sincerely don't believe no votes have been cast on meta this year.

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps confusing the numbers for [Main](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) and [Meta](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) ?

Comment: I realised that just now and edited the Q. :monkey face covering eyes with hands: This does make the issue a *lot* less pressing, imho.

Comment: I just upvoted your Q. Let's see if the vote shows up in the tab.

Comment: For posterity: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58724812#58724812

Comment: At first, only you showed up on the 'year' tab, but when I check now, I do as well. 'Quarter', 'month' and 'week' are still empty....???